# The heuristic of A*/A-star search and its efficiency

Tags: a-star, heuristics

I have a feeling that the more the heuristic underestimates the real cost, the more inefficient (expanding more nodes) it is for A* search to find a optimal solution for path finding problem. Also, when the heuristic perfectly estimates the real cost A* can always find the optimal solution with the least node expansion possible. But how to prove it?